# Virtual keyboard will not disable

Tags: keyboard

I own a Lenovo Thinkpad Helix running the most recent version of Windows 10 and Chrome.
The virtual keyboard is disabled in Chrome settings yet it always appears when I left click on the Chrome search input. The Lenovo device has tablet mode disabled. I would like to know how to disable the virtual keyboard permanently so that it never appears no matter what. Is this a bug in the latest version of Chrome?

Thank you.

Comment: The Windows virtual keyboard or the Chrome virtual keyboard? Please include the version of Windows and Chrome.

Comment: It was the Windows touch keyboard that is normally available in the desktop toolbar at the bottom right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sites explaining how to disable (or enable, again) the virtual keyboard, e.g [Quehow](https://quehow.com/how-to-enable-disable-virtual-keyboard-in-windows-10/4205.html) and [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/259900/how-to-permanently-disable-the-touch-keyboard-in-windows-8-and-10/).

Be sure to disable the *Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service* using the Service CPL, or with *Regedit* at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\TabletInputService`, setting the value `Start` to `4`.

[image: Disable Onscreen Keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable it using `services.msc` from the run prompt: <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
There is an item in the list named "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Service" which I double left clicked on which gave me options for Auto, manual & disable. The disable option stopped it from popping up (manual setting did not stop it from automatically appearing in Chrome).

At the time my Windows 10 Pro still needed cumulative updates 1903 & 1909 which I just finished installing. After those updates it seems to be fixed.
The setting I noted above is now back to "auto" and the virtual keyboard no longer shows up when I use the Google Chrome search input.